# cannot access MongoDB on remote server

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDB on WIndows server as a service. I am trying to access DB from my personal computer using IP of remote server and port 27017. I followed multiple tutorials but everything is failing. Below is the config file.

```
dbpath = C:\DB\data
logpath = C:\DB\log\mongod.log
logappend=true
port = 27017
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
auth = true
```

I have allowed port 27017 in firewall.

[image]

Comment: you need to have correct ip of the server and the port must be open  then you can access . your ip is 0.0.0.0 which is not correct

Comment: I tried that. Still did not work. In fact entering server IP, stopped local connection too.

Comment: Which OS? Which Firewall? How do you connect to the server in order to verify that it is running?

Comment: OS - Amazon Instance of Windows Server. Firewall : Windows firewall. I connect to server via RDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. Everything was setup correctly. I just needed to allow port 27017 on amazon instance too.