# I cannot connect to mongodb, even in same Lan

Tags: mongodb

I used the following config in `mongod.cfg` in **mongdb v4**:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0,192.168.1.120
```

but even from local network I cannot access to server:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a firewall issue. If firewall is running stop it. Also check whether the MongoDB service is running on 0.0.0.0.

Comment: firewall is off because i can access my folders over network but I'm using Eset internet security which is in "paused protection" mode.

Comment: Which OS is hosting the mongoDB server?

Comment: I am Using windows 7 x64. for local test.

Comment: Please check the question I've attached another screenshot of running services and ports.

Comment: Yes there is 0.0.0.0:2717, 192.168.1.120:27017 and 127.0.0.1:2717. are listening.

Comment: I have faced similar issues before and it always ended up being a firewall issue. Stop all Antivirus and security on the server and client.  If you are using any system like hyperV Stop the firewall on that as well. Lastly check the firewall on the router. Stop it if required.  Here are a few links. Hope it helps: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032297/cannot-access-mongodb-on-remote-server

Comment: There was something that blocks network traffic after removing several programs everything gone right.